# Visual Studio 2010 Extensibility, MPF and language services

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vs-extensibility, mpf, languageservice

I am trying to extend Visual Studio 2010 RC to be able to use a custom programming language.

The first two things I've tried to do is a syntax highlight/Intellisense feature (easily done, thanks to "Ook!" sample from PDC09) and a possibility to create new project templates (i.e. be able to open *.myproj files).

For this second task, I can't find any easy tutorials or samples. Most samples are for Visual Studio 2008 (as for IronPython integration) or even VS2003. The few samples available for VS2010 do not work (including MPFProj) or do not compile, and are too hard to understand.

Is there any easy-to-understand sample, either using MPFProj or a standalone solution, showing how to integrate templates for a custom language inside Visual Studio 2010?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems that [MSDN content](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166533%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) is now up-to-date, and explains quite well how to do what I need. By the way, the [MSDN tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/vsxue/archive/2008/03/12/tutorial-a-simple-managed-project-system.aspx) is now available for Visual Studio 2010 (rewritten from an older version for Visual Studio 2008).

Answer (score 1):

Newer samples can be found at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsx/archive/2014/05/30/vs-2013-sdk-samples-released.aspx for Visual Studio SDK 2013