# Is there a simple way to get syntax highlighting for a custom file-type...in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, syntax-highlighting

I'd like to have Visual Studio syntax highlight a simple file format that I use.  The format only contains four different lines of text: comments, blanks lines, lines that are path like, and lines that begin with @ that are also path like.  It would be nice to color code the comment different form the rest of the text, and the comments are simple: a line that begins with a # is a comment.  Of course, if it's simple to add maybe color coding for the 2 different path like lines as well.

Is there a simple way to get Visual Studio to recognize a file extension with these rules?  It would be great if the solution would work for a Visual Studio Express editions too.

Comment: Check out this answer to a similar question:
http://stackoverflow.com/q/4283072/1337519