# How can I create a Visual Studio syntax highligher for a C-like language

Tags: c#, c++, c, visual-studio-2010, syntax-highlighting

I want to have simple syntax highlighting when I am editing code files of a C like language. I know I can just pick C++ syntax highlighting but the language has a lot of keywords similar to HLSL and I want to color them too.

Do I need to write an VS extension for this? Or is this just a matter of proving a VS specific text file that lists keywords, operators, comments, etc?

Where can I find such examples to use as a base?

Comment: Check the answers given for this question. It should answer what you need. http://stackoverflow.com/q/4283072/30225

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a new language for use in Visual Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4283072/how-to-create-a-new-language-for-use-in-visual-studio)

Comment: @NicolBolas I'm not sure if it's close enough for 'Exact Duplicate'.

Comment: If you cant follow the countless VSSDK examples, I am worried...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can find a few examples on codeplex http://www.codeplex.com/site/search?query=highlight&ac=3. Specifically one of the plugins is for HSLS, GLSL, and CG (http://nshader.codeplex.com/)