# New / Custom Visual Studio 2013 Language Service -Very Basic

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I am not looking to do anything fancy just create a bucket for our internal company Visual Studio projects etc.

I have been through the following resources and it seems the codeplex projects have the same behavior as my tutorial walk throughs which tells me I don't understand / know what to look for / learn exactly.

Said behavior is that when my code or the codeplex code compiles and runs with no issues but I don't see the new language show up??? By show up I am expecting to see it in the New Project dialog under templates.

I started here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165744.aspx

and though not the best tutorial I feel I got everything correct. It compiles and runs but my new "Language" doesn't show.

So I did some more searching perhaps another tutorial might fill in some gaps I missed and I watched this video for an hour.

http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/VSIPMarketing/VSX212-Adding-a-Language-Service-into-Visual-Studio-2010

It's for 2010 but felt 2013 and 2010 close enough that it might help....and while I did learn quite a bit it didn't give me what I was expecting.

Another Google result was this SO post ([How to create a new language for use in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4283072/how-to-create-a-new-language-for-use-in-visual-studio)) from which I downloaded OOK from codeplex. Updated references, upgraded from 2010 to 2013 etc.

It compiles and runs but again my language is not "showing"....which is the behavior I had in my tutorial guided solution.

So what am I doing wrong??

All I really want is a language bucket where we can put our internal snippets, customized project templates etc. The c# editor, intellisense, syntax highlighting, etc. are just fine so don't need to extend those at this point.

If someone could please point me in the right direction I would be grateful.

Thank You