# Visual studio 2015 making colour code

Tags: visual-studio-2015, text-editor, visual-studio-extensions, ultraedit

I have my own macro language that is not universal.

Now I am using text editor UltraEdit to modify the language. It seems UltraEdit can understand the common syntax used in my language due to its similarity with other languages and it gives some syntax highlighting. (For example if() will in green colour.)

But when I open the same file in Visual studio 2015, I could not see any syntax highlighting. Due to many reasons I would like to use VS 2015 as my text editor with custom colour coding for my language. Is there any option in Visual studio to add a new language to Tools/ Options -> Text editor with custom colour codes?

Also please note that I do not need any intellisense. My question is very specific to VS2015.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a new language for use in Visual Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4283072/how-to-create-a-new-language-for-use-in-visual-studio)

Comment: I do not need any intellisense, just colour coding. I tried couple of solutions mentioned in the question, but did not go very well in VS 2015. Anyway thanks v much let me know that someone faced this issue before. So there is no off-the-shelf extension in VS and I have to create my own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install a visual studio extension named [Text Macros for Visual Studio 2012/2013/2015](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=XavierPoinas.TextMacrosforVisualStudio201220132015), which brings back support for macros in text/code editors. These macros can be used to automate repetitive text editing tasks.

In addition, you could also [create a custom editor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166460.aspx) with the file extension that you want to be associated with your editor. Then you can special [Syntax Coloring in your Custom Editors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165803.aspx)